# Input syntax for heredoc in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, heredoc

I'm currently learning Unix bash, through the terminal in Ubuntu 16. I was writing a simple script, so I can practice writing code for Unix. Here is a sample of the code:

```
report_uptime(){
cat << _EOF_
    <H2>System Uptime</H2>
    <PRE>$(uptime)</PRE>
    _EOF_
return
}
```

This code doesn't work and the reason is because after cat I'm supposed to use `<<-` instead of `<<`. Sometime `<<` works. So when am I supposed to use `<<` and when am I supposed to use`<<-`?

This works:

```
report_uptime(){
cat <<- _EOF_
    <H2>System Uptime</H2>
    <PRE>$(uptime)</PRE>
    _EOF_
return
}
```

Comment: can you add a case where it works?

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to have space between `<<` and `_EOF_`?

Comment: You could also mention what language or shell this is. bash? dash? ksh?

Comment: OK this is a function, and I have it working. The only thing wrong with it is `<<` is supposed to be `<<-`. The question was not why doesn't this work but when to use `<<` and when to use `<<-`? I'm using bash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't cat syntax per se; it's one of the redirection operators supported by your shell:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

> **3.6.6 Here Documents**
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only *word* (with no trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> <<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or filename expansion is performed on word. If any characters in *word* are quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.
>
> If the redirection operator is ‘<<-’, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing *delimiter*. This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

Comment: And make sure you pay attention to that last line.  "tab characters".  This does, in fact, only strip tab characters, and not spaces.

Comment: That makes sense. When i didn't have [-] it treated the rest of the script as a string.

Answer (score 5):

This is not strictly speaking about the syntax of the `cat` utility, but of the syntax of the shell itself, i.e. of `bash`.

The construct that you're using is called a "here-document". A here-document feeds its contents into the standard input of *whatever* command you put before `<<`.

The syntax is this:

```
command <<word
...
contents
...
END_TAG
```

The `word` here is either exactly the same as the `END_TAG`, or it may be `'END_TAG'`, `-END_TAG`, or `-'END_TAG'`.

- **`END_TAG`: *Without* single quotes**, the contents of the here-document will undergo substitution.  This means that any variable, or simply put, "anything that contains a `$`" will be replaced with its value.

  ```
  $ tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' <<TR_END
  > This is my $HOME
  > TR_END
  THIS IS MY /USERS/KK
  ```

  (The `>`, a greater-than sign and a space, is what's called *the secondary prompt*. I get that because I'm typing this directly into the shell, and it needs more lines of input before it can execute the whole command. It is not typed by me.)
- **`'END_TAG'`: *With* single quotes**, the contents of the here-document will *not* undergo substitution. This means, for example, that if you write `$HOME` in the here-document, it will be fed into the command just like that, not like `/home/myname` (or whatever your home directory may be).

  ```
  $ tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' <<'TR_END'
  > This is my $HOME
  > TR_END
  THIS IS MY $HOME
  ```
- ***With* a leading dash (`-`)**, the shell will strip off all tabs (but not spaces) at the start of each line of the here-document, including the line with the `END_TAG` at the end.

  ```
  $ tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' <<-TR_END
  >       This line has a tab.
  > This one does not.
  > TR_END
  THIS LINE HAS A TAB.
  THIS ONE DOES NOT.
  ```
- ***Without* a leading dash**, the shell will *not* strip off tabs.  The `END_TAG` needs to be the first (and only) thing on the line ending the here-document.

  ```
  $ tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' <<TR_END
  >       This line has a tab.
  > This one does not.
  > TR_END
      THIS LINE HAS A TAB.
  THIS ONE DOES NOT.
  ```

The `bash` shell also has something called "here-strings".  It works in a similar fashion, but you're only feeding a single line into the command:

```
command <<<word
```

For example:

```
$ tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' <<<"hello world!"
HELLO WORLD!
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the end marker should not be indented. Move it to column 1. Also remove the `return` statement, and it works for me in bash.

Comment: The code at the bottom works. My question was not,"Why doesn't my code work?". The question is, when do I use `<<` and when do I use `<<-`, because in the cause of this function `<<` will not work but `<<-` will.